# Power BI (DAX): SUM of Total Differences and keep all filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have data like this:

> category : dim table
>
> value last week : calculation table
>
> value current week : calculation
>
> table diff : calculation table

| category | value last week | value current week | Diff | sum of diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 88% | 88% | 0.00% | ? |
| b | 87% | 90% | 3.00% | ? |
| c | 0% | 0% | 0.00% | ? |
| a | 69% | 70% | 1.00% | ? |

> I need the value SUM of total diff (0%+3%+0%+1%) = 4%, the result should be:

| category | value last week | value current week | Diff | sum of diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 88% | 88% | 0.00% | 4% |
| b | 87% | 90% | 3.00% | 4% |
| c | 0% | 0% | 0.00% | 4% |
| a | 69% | 70% | 1.00% | 4% |

I try to create a measure but the result is still incorrect:

```
sum of diff = CALCULATE(SUMX(VALUES('dim table'[category]), [Diff]), ALLSELECTED('dim table'[category]))



Diff = value current week - value last week

value current week = CALCULATE(
'table1'[total1],
LASTDATE('Calendar'[Date])
)

value last week =CALCULATE(
'calculation'[value current week ],
DATEADD('Calendar'[Date],-7,DAY)
)
```

what measure should I create?

I hope i'm clear enough.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You can use this measure

```
sum of diff = CALCULATE(SUM('dim table'[Diff]), ALL(dim table))
```

Comment: doesn't work, the format of SUM can't be like that, because dim table and Diff are different.

Comment: What is the name of above table shown in picture? Use that table inplace of dim table,

Comment: category : dim table, 

value last week : calculation table, 

value current week : calculation, 

table diff : calculation table

Comment: IF I understood correctly value last week, value current week, diff are from a calculated Table. What is the name of that table? Give that in code

Comment: I already edit my question and add the code above, please kindly check